# Blue Alert in VOY: "Dragon's Teeth"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Why doesn't Captain Janeway initiate Blue Alert in the episode "Dragon's Teeth"? Note that the threat from the Turei had ended before she gave the order to land the ship. (Netflix time index: 6:20)

Comment: Memory Alpha states that *'the USS Voyager did make a landing while at red alert without switching to blue alert status. (VOY: [Dragon's Teeth](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon%27s_Teeth_(episode)))'* ([source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blue_alert)) I'll have to rewatch the episode closely to see who is correct.

Comment: That's correct. They did make the landing while at red alert, but that doesn't imply that the threat from the Turei was still in effect as the radiation in the planet's atmosphere prevented further pursuit. Now taking into consideration the source above, is it possible to have blue alert active during red alert?

Comment: There is no purple alert. Different ship statuses (red alert, blue alert, etc) have different protocols to follow. It's wiser to keep your cew at red alert ship status than cancel the red alert and immediately initiate a blue alert. Blue alert was only the **minimum** ship status for a landing; there is nothing prohibiting a higher state of readiness.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that the colors could mix. I agree that it was wiser to keep the ship at red alert in that situation, but according to the source, "Blue alert was the minimum **required** ship status for landing an _Intrepid_-class starship" which means the least they were to do is to initiate blue alert.

Comment: I don't read it that way. Different ship statuses have degrees of importance. It's like DEFCON-1, DEFCON-2, etc. If you are already at a higher state of emergency then red trumps blue. I'll try to expand my answer to that effect shortly.

Comment: Reminds me of Red Dwarf. Rimmer: We can't afford to take any chances. Jump up to red alert. Kryten: Are you sure, sir? It does mean changing the bulb.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the imminent threat from the [Turei](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Turei) had passed, Voyager was still at red alert status when landing on the planet.

There is no purple (combination of red and blue) alert status; it has to be one or the other and [Captain Janeway](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kathryn_Janeway) decided to remain at the higher red alert ship status instead of cancelling it and initiating a whole new blue alert emergency protocol.

> On a vessel with landing capabilities, such as the Intrepid-class, blue alert was called as an indication that the ship was preparing either to land or to take off; the crew would then need to report to code blue stations, in order to aid in the landing/liftoff procedures. (VOY: "The 37's", "Demon") **Blue alert was the minimum required ship status for landing an Intrepid-class starship**, as the USS Voyager did make a landing while at red alert without switching to blue alert status. (VOY: "Dragon's Teeth")
>  <sub>*source:* [Memory Alpha - Blue Alert](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blue_alert)</sub>

Different ship statuses ([red alert](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Red_alert), [yellow alert](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Yellow_alert), [blue alert](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blue_alert), etc) have different protocols to follow. It's wiser to keep your crew at red alert ship status than cancel the red alert and immediately initiate a blue alert. Blue alert was only the **minimum** ship status for a landing; there is nothing prohibiting a higher state of readiness.

Comment: Why does it matter that Voyager was still at red alert status when it landed on the planet?

Comment: Because if it wasn't then the ship should have been at blue alert to make the landing. Surely red alert (when your ship is being attacked) is a higher state of readiness than a blue alert (ship docking or landing).

Comment: I don't recall it ever being mentioned what "code blue stations" are, for all we know they could well be the same places the crew would report due during a red alert